# Issues with alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,...) and alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, ...)

Tags: android, alarmmanager

The manifest of my Android app states

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="14"
          android:targetSdkVersion="14"
          android:maxSdkVersion="22" />
```

According to the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html#setRepeating(int,%20long,%20long,%20android.app.PendingIntent)) for API level 14, for alarms set via  `alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,...)` and `alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP,...)`:

> Applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will
>   continue to see the previous behavior in which all alarms are
>   delivered exactly when requested.

So since the targetSdkVersion is 14, the calls above should provide exact alarms even in higher SDK versions.

My issue is that, on phones running higher SDK versions, e.g. `VERSION_SDK_INT: 23` there seem to be delays in the firing of the alarms set, which seem to range from a couple of minutes to several hours.

I would be grateful for any suggestions on how to interpret this behaviour, and possible solutions. Many thanks.